# Why is NSDate different inside of a string?

Tags: swift, nsdate

In playground, I am testing some code.

If I type in

```
NSDate()
```

then I get **"Nov 28, 2014, 7:56 PM"**

But, if I type in

```
var dateString: String = "\(NSDate())"
```

then I get **"2014-11-29 01:56:45 +0000"**

Why is the default time different within a string than a simple NSDate() declaration?

Comment: In the first case I think you're seeing the debugger's presentation.  In the second case you see the result of doing `[myNSDate description]`.  The debugger presumably presents in the default timezone and locale.

Comment: If you want to control the string representation (beyond the `description`), consider using use `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In playground, I am testing some code.
>
> If I type in
>
> NSDate()  then I get "Nov 28, 2014, 7:56 PM"

this is your local time but you can't store timezone into a NSDate object.

> But, if I type in
>
> var dateString: String = "(NSDate())" then I get "2014-11-29 01:56:45
>   +0000"

this is Greenwich Mean Time which and thats how it is stored into your NSDate

```
let dateString = "\(Date())"
```

is the same as:

```
let dateString = Date().description
```

if you would like to know the localtime of a Date you can do as follow:

edit/update Swift 3 or later:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let localTimestamp: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .full
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
extension Date {
    var localTimestamp: String {
        return Formatter.localTimestamp.string(from: self)
    }
}

Date().localTimestamp  // "6:40:19 PM Brasilia Standard Time"
```